# WebService cannot communicate with another WS via IIS but it can via VisualStudio

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, visual-studio-2010, iis

First of welcome as it is my first post.
I developed WebService (.NET 4.0) which is connecting to two other WebServices. One of these two is external, second one is internal but located on another server.

When developing in Visual Studio, communication was perfect, everything was fine - my WS against two other. But when I moved my WS to IIS on a server I received issue:

```
There was no endpoint listening at <<<url>>> that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

In inner exception I have (sorry for german;]):

```
Server stack trace: 
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   bei MessagingAgent.eCallWS.eCallSoap.SendSMSBasic(SendSMSBasicRequest request)
   bei MessagingAgent.eCallWS.eCallSoapClient.MessagingAgent.eCallWS.eCallSoap.SendSMSBasic(SendSMSBasicRequest request) in C:\_projects\MessagingAgent\Service References\eCallWS\Reference.cs:Zeile 888.
   bei MessagingAgent.eCallWS.eCallSoapClient.SendSMSBasic(String AccountName, String AccountPassword, String Address, String Message, String JobID, String SMSCallback, String Notification, String Answer, String SendDate, String MsgType, String NoLog, String AlwaysNotification) in C:\_projects\MessagingAgent\Service References\eCallWS\Reference.cs:Zeile 906.
   bei MessagingAgent.SmsSender.SendSmsBasic(String address, String message, String jobId) in C:\_projects\MessagingAgent\SMS\SmsSender.cs:Zeile 46.
   bei MessagingAgent.Service1.SendSMSWithJob(String telNo, String content, String jobID) in C:\_projects\MessagingAgent\SMSProvider.asmx.cs:Zeile 48.
```

In order to pass more information - WS hosted on IIS 6.1. I created new ApplicationPool for that

Can you help me somehow?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the proxy server on our corporate network. I had to explicity state it in my web.config and it worked fine.

Here is what I added to web.config:

```
 <system.net>
<defaultProxy>
      <proxy
        proxyaddress="http://webproxy.mycompany.com:8080"
        bypassonlocal="true"
      />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

What confuses me is that without the above statement it worked fine when it was hosted by the Visual Studio Development server but not on IIS.  Never mind - I have it working now